# Angular material align menu tabs in the center

Tags: angular, angular-material

How can I align the mat menu tabs in the center?

f.e.

```
<mat-toolbar>
    <nav mat-tab-nav-bar aria-label="weather navigation links" [backgroundColor]="tabNavBackground">
        <a mat-tab-link routerLink="/lala">lala</a>
        <a mat-tab-link routerLink="/lala2">lala2</a>
        <a mat-tab-link routerLink="/lala3">lala3</a>
      </nav>
</mat-toolbar>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the CSS property [`flex`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_flex.asp).

Add this class e.g. in your *styles.css* or in the CSS file of your component:

```
.toolbar-flex {
  flex: 1 0.5 auto;
}
```

Your HTML would then look like:

```
<mat-toolbar>
    <span class="toolbar-flex"></span>
    <nav mat-tab-nav-bar aria-label="weather navigation links" [backgroundColor]="tabNavBackground">
        <a mat-tab-link routerLink="/lala">lala</a>
        <a mat-tab-link routerLink="/lala2">lala2</a>
        <a mat-tab-link routerLink="/lala3">lala3</a>
    </nav>
    <span class="toolbar-flex"></span>
</mat-toolbar>
```

Answer (score 9):

You can add *mat-align-tabs="center"* to the nav to make it center...
See below...

```
<mat-toolbar>
 <nav mat-tab-nav-bar mat-align-tabs="center" aria-label="weather navigation links" [backgroundColor]="tabNavBackground">
    <a mat-tab-link routerLink="/lala">lala</a>
    <a mat-tab-link routerLink="/lala2">lala2</a>
    <a mat-tab-link routerLink="/lala3">lala3</a>
 </nav>
</mat-toolbar>
```

Comment: This is the most up-to-date answer according to the Angular Material API: https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/overview#label-alignment

Answer (score 0):

I have snippet that's running like this right now:

```
<mat-toolbar>
  <div fxFlex fxLayout fxLayoutAlign="flex-start">
    <ul fxLayout fxLayoutGap="10px">
      <li><a routerLink="/signup">signup</a></li>
      <li><a routerLink="/login">login</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</mat-toolbar>
```

Now, I just tried `center` as the value for `fxLayoutAligh` and it worked (the remaining value is `flex-end`). So for you, if you maybe remove the `span` element and wrap the entire `mat-toolbar` body inside a `<div fxFlex fxLayout fxLayoutAlign="center">`, that should do it.